# Getting the last post from a Google+ company Page using REST API

Tags: google-plus

I am developing a website for a hotel company. The client wants the home page of the new website to show the last post made on its Google+ Page. Unfortunately, I cannot rely on the "embedded post" feature, because the layout will have to be fully custom. Neither my company nor my client is a Google Partner or owns a Google Apps for Businsess account. Reading through the documentation, it seems that Pages API are accessible only by partners.
Two questions:

1. Do I actually need to use Pages API in order to access the company page stream?
2. Do we actually have to become Google Partners just to perform such a simple integration task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to walk along a long, winding and useless road. The post stream of a page can be retrieved with the *Activities.list* method, and the last post can be selected by specifying a proper value for the *maxResults* parameter

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list﻿

By using the "API explorer", we can see that the *userId* field can actually be filled with a "page id". For example, if we want to obtain the stream of the following page:
https://plus.google.com/102884112172662547291
we shall pass 102884112172662547291 as *userId*.